# What is the shelf life of Pylsusinnep (Icelandic mustard)? Does it need to be kept refrigerated before opening?

Tags: food-safety, storage-method, refrigerator, mustard

I'd like to purchase a case of Pylsusinnep mustard to save on expensive shipping costs versus buying a small number of bottles, but I'm unable to find any information about its shelf life.

[image: Bottle of Pylsusinnep mustard]

Comment: Does it have a "best-before" kind of date on the packaging ? A quick google does return one hit that says 6 months to 1 year.

Comment: Regardless of whether it "has to be" refrigerated before opening, that's a good idea if you have available fridge space and want to extend storage life (or you just keep it in the old-fashioned cool root cellar - not quite so cold, but still a cool and dark space, and no operating costs.)

Answer (score 1):

After receiving my first batch, it appears that 6 months is the "best fyrir" ("best until") date.  It didn't come in any special refrigerated packaging, but I agree with Ecnerwal that it should be kept someplace cool to help extend the shelf life.